# How to set mysql global variables running on Docker instance started by TestContainers

Tags: mysql, docker, environment-variables, testcontainers

I am currently running a Java Spring application using TestContainers to manage my datasources.
I am having issues setting global variables for my MySQL instance on Docker during initialization of the docker instance.

I've tried a few things.

TestContainers has a method `execInContainer` which takes a string of commands.

```java
container.execInContainer("mysqld", "--character_set_server=utf8");
```

In addition, you can also run an init script using
`.withInitScript("mysql_test_init.sql");`

```sql
SET @@global.character_set_client = 'utf8';
SET @@global.character_set_server = 'utf8';
```

Using `execInContainer` seems to do nothing and does not change the variable(s) in MySQL.

Using the script fails due to Docker using a non-root user to make changes.

```
Access denied for user 'test'@'%' (using password: YES)
```

Is there a way I can easily change/configure the global variables of MySQL. Am I doing something wrong?

Some parameters I would like to change:

- `character_set_client`
- `character_set_connection`

Thank you.